# CQLSH ImportError: cannot import name ensure_str

Tags: python, cassandra, centos, cqlsh

I have installed `Cassandra` database on my CentOs system. after that, I tried to install the Cqlsh package using this command `sudo yum install cqlsh` and it has been installed successfully. but when I tried to run `cqlsh` from the terminal, the following error appears:

> ImportError: cannot import name ensure_str

somewhere in the code, it tries to load a library named `six` that contains `ensure_str`. the error does not say that it can not find a module named `six`, the python interpreter can find the library but can not import it!
I have tried googling but none of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you have to install cqlsh separately? It's already in included in the Cassandra installation. Cheers!

Comment: I just used 'yum' to install Cassandra, but CentOS did not recognize 'cqlsh' command! On my Ubuntu, I can run 'cqlsh' after the installation and none of these problems exists.

Comment: I got this message before installing 'cqlsh' using 'yum': ImportError: No module named cqlshlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a few hours of googling and struggling with the code, finally, I find out the solution. and I'm going to share it with others.

apparently, the problem is the new version of `six` (v=1.7.3) which is not compatible with my system. However, Cassandra copies the last version of `six` into the following path:

> /usr/share/cassandra/lib/six-1.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.zip

then `cqlsh` try to force the python interpreter to import the library from this path by adding the following lines to the code.

```
third_parties = ('futures-', 'six-', 'geomet-')

for lib in third_parties:
    lib_zip = find_zip(lib)
    if lib_zip:
        sys.path.insert(0, lib_zip)
```

no matter if you have another version of `six` installed on your system, it always tries to import the library from the Cassandra folder.

So, I have just deleted these lines from `cqlsh` file using this command:

```
vim /usr/bin/cqlsh
```

Then I try to install the last compatible version on `six` using this command:

```
yum install six
```

That's it! problem solved and now I'm using `cqlsh` without any problem.
I hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

We've had reports of this being a problem on CentOS specifically with version 6.7 but it possibly affects the 7.x releases too.

It appears that the wrong Python is getting called. This isn't strictly a Cassandra issue but a problem with the Python on the machine. You can verify which Python gets run with:

```
$ which python
```

As a workaround, you should be able to run `cqlsh` using the system Python as follows:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/cqlsh
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip3` to install or upgrade to the current `six`.

Edit a copy of cqlsh.  Change

```
third_parties = ('futures-', 'six-', 'geomet-')
```

to

```
third_parties = ('futures-', 'geomet-')
```

Not proud, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Used `pip3` to install, and found this issue as well.

For me, removing six dependencies from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` was the only thing that worked.

`rm six-1.11.0.egg-info` and `rm -r six-1.11.0.egg-info`

I couldn't uninstall it with pip3, so manual removal was the way to go, followed by a `pip3 install six`

Once that was back in place, cqlsh ran without issue.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers didn't work for me, I had to delete the Cassandra included six package, and then `cqlsh` used the system-wide package.

`mv /usr/share/cassandra/lib/six-1.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.zip /usr/share/cassandra/lib/six-1.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.zip.bak`

Maybe an older version of Cassandra installed, and a newer version of cqlsh?

https://community.datastax.com/questions/12085/unable-to-connect-to-cqlsh.html